# Android ParallaxHeaderViewPager in ScrollView not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I'm using [Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager](https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager) in my new project. It's working perfectly using a listview inside fragments, but it's not working when I use a scrollview (the header gets fixed and doesn't make the same effect as in a listview fragment). Any help would be appreciated.
Here is my code:

**fragment_lore.xml** (Not working)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewLore">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/championLore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</ScrollView>
```

**LoreFragment.java**

```
public class LoreFragment extends ScrollTabHolderFragment implements OnScrollListener {

    private int mPosition;
    private ScrollView mScrollView;
    private int mTabBarHeight;
    private int mTopImageHeight;

    public static final LoreFragment newInstance(Integer position, Integer pos){
        LoreFragment fragment = new LoreFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position",position);
        args.putInt("pos",pos);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPosition = getArguments().getInt("position");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lore,container,false);
        mScrollView = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewLore);
        mTabBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tab_bar_height);
        KenBurnsView headerImg = (KenBurnsView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.header_picture);
        mTopImageHeight = headerImg.getHeight();
        TextView loreView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.championLore);
        Integer pos = Integer.valueOf(getArguments().getInt("pos"));
        String lore = Cache.champions.get(pos).getDescription();
        lore = lore.replace("<br>","\n");
        loreView.setText(lore);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void adjustScroll(int scrollHeight) {
        if (scrollHeight == 0 && mScrollView.getScrollY() > mTopImageHeight - mTabBarHeight) {
            // ScrollView does not need to adjust scroll, as the tab bar is its sticky position
            return;
        }
        mScrollView.scrollTo(mScrollView.getScrollX(), -scrollHeight + mTopImageHeight - mTabBarHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (mScrollTabHolder != null)
            mScrollTabHolder.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount, mPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // nothing
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class ChampionDetailsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ScrollTabHolder, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
...
@Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> scrollTabHolders = mPagerAdapter.getScrollTabHolders();
        ScrollTabHolder currentHolder = scrollTabHolders.valueAt(position);

        currentHolder.adjustScroll((int) (mHeader.getHeight() + mHeader.getTranslationY()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount, int pagePosition) {
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == pagePosition) {
            int scrollY = getScrollY(view);
            mHeader.setTranslationY(Math.max(-scrollY, mMinHeaderTranslation));
            float ratio = clamp(mHeader.getTranslationY() / mMinHeaderTranslation, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            setTitleAlpha(clamp(5.0F * ratio - 4.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void adjustScroll(int scrollHeight) {
        // nothing
    }

    public int getScrollY(AbsListView view) {
        View c = view.getChildAt(0);
        if (c == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int firstVisiblePosition = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int top = c.getTop();

        int headerHeight = 0;
        if (firstVisiblePosition >= 1) {
            headerHeight = mHeaderHeight;
        }

        return -top + firstVisiblePosition * c.getHeight() + headerHeight;
    }

    public static float clamp(float value, float max, float min) {
        return Math.max(Math.min(value, min), max);
    }

public int getActionBarHeight() {
        if (mActionBarHeight != 0) {
            return mActionBarHeight;
        }
        getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, mTypedValue, true);
        mActionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(mTypedValue.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        return mActionBarHeight;
    }
...
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private Integer pos;
        private ScrollTabHolder mListener;
        private SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> mScrollTabHolders;
        ...

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            mScrollTabHolders = new SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder>();
        }

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Integer pos) {
            super(fm);
            this.pos=pos;
            mScrollTabHolders = new SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder>();

        }

        public void setTabHolderScrollingContent(ScrollTabHolder listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

...

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            ScrollTabHolderFragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = (ScrollTabHolderFragment) ListViewFragment.newInstance(position,pos);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = (ScrollTabHolderFragment) LoreFragment.newInstance(position,pos);
                    break;
            }

            mScrollTabHolders.put(position, fragment);
            if (mListener != null) {
                fragment.setScrollTabHolder(mListener);
            }

            return fragment;
        }

        public SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> getScrollTabHolders() {
            return mScrollTabHolders;
        }
```

Also, I tried [that article](http://nerds.airbnb.com/host-experience-android/) but I couldn't fix my scrollview. Let me know if you need more pieces of my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm as well trying to understand how to set the scrollView height with respect to the header image!
I guess you were trying to implement what is shown here - http://nerds.airbnb.com/host-experience-android/

Answer (score 0):

You better look at this http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/11/20/making-your-action-bar-not-boring/ link to understand your program, because the ParallaxHeaderViewPager was done using this article. 
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a demo with scrollview instead of listview, and use fragment as container view instead activity.

[Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager_ScrollView](https://github.com/itlonewolf/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager_ScrollView)

Maybe late for u, but i hope it`s useful to others...